# Formatting a Javascript String date to a specifc format

Tags: javascript, datejs

I have a String like `2016/1/1`, which I want to change into a proper format like  `2016/01/01` (`yyyy/mm/dd`). The output format should also be a String.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: What makes this a proper format?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a piece of code I often use:

```
function yyyymmdd(dte) {
  var _date = new Date(dte);
  var mm = _date.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = _date.getDate();

  return [_date.getFullYear(),
          "/",
          (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
          "/",
          (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
         ].join('');
}

var date = "1/1/2010";
yyyymmdd(dte); // returns "2010/01/01"
```

This is simple a format I've come up with that I like.  There are probably many ways to approach this code.

This is a slightly cleaner version that was suggested to me later.

```
function yyyymmdd(dte) {
  var _date = new Date(dte);
  var mm = _date.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = _date.getDate();

  return [_date.getFullYear(),
          (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
          (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
         ].join('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling dates in Javascript can be a pain, an alternate solution is to use `momentjs`

The library can be found [here](http://momentjs.com/)

You can then easily format date in various different formats using the `.format()` option:

```
var dateTime = new Date();
dateTime = moment(dateTime).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Datejs](http://datejs.com), you pass a format to `.toString()`.

**Example**

```
Date.parse('2016/1/1').toString('yyyy-MM-dd')
// "2016-01-01"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var now = new Date();
    var date = now.getDate();
    var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
    var monthName = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August','September', 'Octobor', 'November', 'December']
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    if (date <= 9) {
        date = '0'+ date
    }
    console.log(date + '-' + monthName[month] + '-' +year);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with an explanation. Code without explanation does not make for a good answer to a question.